# Can't retrieve data from session variable - PHP Number guessing game

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am building a number guessing game and need to create a session variable to hold the randomized target number until the user submits the correct guess. I also need to print the number of attempts after the user submits the correct answer.

I set my session variable and used a hidden field to hold the counter. I don't know if the hidden field works bc when I submit a guess, my code prints out the first if statement of the check() function..ALL THE TIME.

I think it has something to do with the session variable (and of course my code), but I can't figure it out. I've been working on this for two days now and feeling the frustrations. Any help would be amazing. Here's my full code below:

```
    <?php session_start() ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Number Guessing Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Guess the number</h1>
      <p>I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 5. Can you guess what it is?<br>
        In less than 3 tries?</p>
      <?php
        extract($_REQUEST);
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
        // check to see if this is start of game
        if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "guess")) {
          check();
        } else {
          setTarget();
        } //end if
        // set targetNum session variable
        // increment counter by 1

        function setTarget() {
          $targetNum = rand(1, 5);
          $_SESSION["targetNum"] = $targetNum;
          $counter++;
        print <<<HERE
          <form action="" method="post">
            <input type = "text"
                   name = "guess">
            <input type = "hidden"
                   name = "counter"
                   value = "$counter">
            <h2>Target Number: $targetNum</h2>
            <h3>The counter is at: $counter</h3>
            <br>
            <button type = "submit">
              SUBMIT GUESS
            </button>
          </form>
    HERE;
    }

        function check() {
          global $counter;
          print <<<HERE
            <form action="" method="post">
            <input type = "text"
                   name = "guess"
                   value= "$guess">
            <input type = "hidden"
                   name = "counter"
                   value = "$counter">
            <h2>Target Number: $targetNum</h2>
            <h3>The counter is at: $counter</h3>
            <br>
            <button type = "submit">
              SUBMIT GUESS
            </button>
            </form>
    HERE;
        if ($guess == $_SESSION['$targetNum']) {
          print "<h3>Awesome. You guessed it in $counter attempt(s)</h3>";
          unset($_SESSION["targetNum"]);
          $count = 0;
          print "<a href='numberGuessingGame.php'>TRY AGAIN</a>";
        } else if ($guess > $_SESSION['$targetNum']) {
          print "<h3>Too high. Guess again.</h3>";
        } else if ($guess < $_SESSION['$targetNum']) {
          print "<h3>Too low. Guess again.</h3>";
        } else {
          print "I don't know what that is...";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$guess` variable is never set to the POST value (Correction: you're using extract but I'd advise against it).  You are also changing the value of your session array key when you add a '$':

```
$guess = $_POST['guess'];
if ($guess == $_SESSION['targetNum']) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You made two basic, but severe errors.

First: DO not set the error level to exclude notices when developing! That way you will never spot typos in variable or array index names. Remove `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`, or replace it with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Second: You use `extract($_REQUEST);` - using that function is asking for trouble. PHP has a long history of security vulnerabilities because of the "register_globals" feature, which introduces global variables just because some key=value pair in the request data was parsed. It took years to remove that feature. You are re-implementing it without any security precaution by using that function, and with no real benefit.

Remove that `extract($_REQUEST);` function, and use `$_REQUEST['varname']` instead of `$varname` for all variables that come from the remote browser.